# Remove external files from my project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I had 2 files .sql in my project wish was at the root then I deleted them with the button move to trash but they are still here when I print with this function :

> `NSArray *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
>   pathsForResourcesOfType:@"sql" inDirectory:@"/"];
>   NSLog(@"file path : %@",filePath);`

The result is :

```
 "/Users/Fabrik/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/46A082C2-6BCD-4904-A882-798A8642FFE1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/547F421A-1934-49FF-B166-8C6AFB9F8ED9/iOSFramework.app//DELL_001_01_CREATE_SCHEMA.sql",
 "/Users/Fabrik/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/46A082C2-6BCD-4904-A882-798A8642FFE1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/547F421A-1934-49FF-B166-8C6AFB9F8ED9/iOSFramework.app//DELL_001_02_CREATE_DATA.sql"
```

I reseted all the setting but they are still here.
How can I remove them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Product > Clean

Then go to Product while pressing `option` in your keyboard and do Product > Clean Build Folder.

If this doesn't work just delete the app in the simulator and build your target again.